# Checkbox value is saved shared preference in android?

Tags: android

Hi i have created base adapter in list view.I have implemented custom check box.What we need means if i have clicked multiple item saved in share preference.if i have unchecked means remove that item in that share preference.Please give me solution .

Here i have mention below this code :

```
holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

        if (checkBoxState[position] = true) {
            // Calculate function
            chk = Integer.toString(v.getId());
            total += Double.valueOf(category.arrListPrice
                    .get(position));
            System.out.println("********************Checked"
                    + total);
            checkboxvalue.add(chk);
            adapter_list.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    } else {

        if (checkBoxState[position] = false) {
            System.out.println("*********************unchecked"
                    + total);
            total -= Double.valueOf(category.arrListPrice
                    .get(position));
            checkboxvalue.remove(chk);
            adapter_list.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    if (listener != null) {
        Log.e("Callback", Double.toString(total));
        listener.totalAmount(Double.toString(total));

    }

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void saveCheckBox(position int, boolean isChecked){
   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putBoolean("checkbox_"+position,isChecked);
    editor.commit();
 }


  public boolean getCheckBoxState(int position){
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
  prefs.getBoolean("checkbox_"+position, false);
 }
```

This will work only if position is always the same for checkboxes, if it is different you should find other way to determine which checkbox was clicked

Comment: You should definitely read about SharedPreferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html  there you can see that you can store all primitive types, and adittionaly String Set. So instead of putBoolean just use putString, and instead of getBoolean - getString